# Python: Removing duplicate strings and staying within certain parameters

Tags: python, authentication, duplicates, passwords, unique

Currently, I am designing a credential database meant to hold a servername, username, and password in a text file. However, for the servername and passwords I am trying to make them unique (no two credentials / logins can have the same servername AND password, usernames can be duplicated).

For example,

```
# This is NOT acceptable because the servername is duplicated.
servername : username : password
google : john : 123
google : john : 321

# This is acceptable because the servername and password are unique.
servername : username : password
google : john : 123
yahoo : john : 321
```

I have searched stackoverflow for some answers but I was not able to find exactly what I am looking for. In my program's current state, when credentials are entered, they are simply listed right underneath the existing one and continue to add each additional credential without checking for duplicates.

```
# Creates the file "passdatabase.txt" for use with this code.
with open('passdatabase.txt', 'a+') as searchfile:
    searchfile.close()

# Here I initialize the variable / count for the while loop
x = 1

print("\n======================="+
      "\nYou chose to add a credential."
      "\n-----------------------")
# User enters in a server name to be saved.
addservername = input("Server Name: ")
# User enters in a username to be saved.
addusername = input("Username: ")
# User enters in a password to be saved.
addpassword = input("Password: ")
# All inputs are combined to create a single variable in the format (servername : username : password)
addCredential = addservername + " : " + addusername + " : " + addpassword

# Loops until the user enters a valid submission (either [y] or [n]) to confirm information.
while x == 1:
    # Input information is displayed for user to confirm.
    confirmCredential = input("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~" +
                              "\nPlease verify the entered credentials.\n" +
                              "\nServer Name: [" +
                              addservername + "]" +
                              "\nUsername: [" +
                              addusername + "]" +
                              "\nPassword: [" +
                              addpassword + "]" +
                              "\n\nIs the information correct? (y/n): ")
    print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
    if confirmCredential == "y":
        x = 2
        with open('passdatabase.txt', 'r') as searchfile:
            lines_seen = set(open('passdatabase.txt'))
            for addCredential in (searchfile, 1):
                if addCredential not in lines_seen:
                    with open('passdatabase.txt', 'a+') as searchfile:
                        # I set the format of the credential to save in the text file as
                        # servername : username : password.
                        searchfile.write("\n" + addservername + " : " + addusername + " : " + addpassword)
                        print("[!] SUCCESS! Your credentials have successfully been stored [!]" +
                              "\n=======================")
                        # This breaks the for loop so it does not continue the code.
                        break
                else:
                    print('Duplicate credential detected!')
    elif confirmCredential == "n":
        x = 2
        print("[!] Your credentials have not been stored [!]" +
              "\n=======================")
    else:
        print("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@" +
              "\n[!!!ERROR!!!] PLEASE ENTER EITHER [y] OR [n]. [!!!ERROR!!!]\n" +
              "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@")
```

My questions / requests in one simple list are as follows:
- How do I ensure that the user can only enter in **unique** entries for their servername and password credentials while allowing duplicate username entries?
- If a duplicate is detected, I would like the code to stop from going further and ask the user for input again until a proper unique credential is provided.
- Should I be using a set or an array? (Data-order does not matter)
- I've seen quite a few duplicate checking scripts that involve the use of 2 .txt files, is this possible with only 1?
- In the future I plan on adding encryption to the password entries, password strength checker, and possibly a credential log (of who has logged in).
- Any input is welcome as I am always willing to learn!

I am fairly new to Python coding and I would really just like some guidance on what I should be looking into next, I'm honestly not sure if I am even headed in the right direction.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use `sqlite` instead of pure text file.

If you really want to implement database feature in a txt file:

Use `set` for tuple(servername, password), check if exist before appending to file. Remember to load all exist ones from your txt file before ask user to input.

You'd better use a file lock to make sure that only one instance of your script run at the same time.